# What is the key combination to send NUL byte from a terminal?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminal, putty

This may sound ridiculous but I need to send something like `<policy-file-request/>` followed by a `nul byte` from a terminal to a XML socket server.
I am using PUTTY but I tried all sorts of combinations like `\0` or `/0` or `\u0000` but to no avail.
I'm wondering if there is a specific key combination for this or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: Seems not to be programming related. Superuser perhaps?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but Alt+000 (on the numeric keypad) will do it in a windows command prompt.

Comment: Possibly not programming related, but a question programmers will have an answer to. I say keep it here on SO :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Alt+000 doesn't work out in Putty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what PuTTY is emulating (different emulators might map it differently) but it's typically `^@` -- that is, `Ctrl + @`.

Comment: Well I have clicked RAW data in PUTTY. I don't know what kind of emulator is that? I will try this command though.

Comment: Well Ctrl + @ worked for me thanks, Phew! that was quite a struggle. ;)